# Telnet library in C/ C++ Linux that can login to telnet server

Tags: library, c++, c

Anyone aware of a telnet library written in c or c++ (Linux) that I can use to login with password to telnet server?

I got this [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349346/telnet-library-for-c) however it requires [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), which I don't want to use.

I want to login to the following server and send command: 198.182.241.14 (hosted by: Pittsburg State University, Kansas, USA) - login: library

Comment: Any reason you *don't* want to use BOOST?
Also do you care about pricing? how about licensing?

Comment: There probably isn't one because telnet is so simple that nobody has bothered.  You just connect a port on a socket and send probably the simplest header format you've ever seen.  Busy box has a basic c implementation to start from though.